# Measurable dependence of an integral

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_i,\mathcal A_i)$ be a measurable space and $f:\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\to\mathbb R$ be bounded and $\mathcal A_1\otimes\mathcal A_2$-measurable. If $\mu$ is a finite measure on $(\Omega_1,\mathcal A_1)$, we know that $g(\omega_2):=\int f(\omega_1,\omega_2)\:\mu({\rm d}\omega_1)\,\text{ for }\omega_2\in\Omega$ is $\mathcal A_2$-measurable.

Now let $\pi$ be a Markov kernel from a measurable space $(E,\mathcal E)$ to $(\Omega_2,\mathcal A_2)$. Are we able to show $g(\omega_1,x):=\int\pi(x,\:{\rm d}\omega_2)f(\omega_1,\omega_2)\,\text{ for }(\omega_1,x)\in\Omega_1\times E$ is $\mathcal A_1\otimes\mathcal E$-measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is. By the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem and MCT, we only need to prove measurability when $f$ has the form $f(w_1, w_2) = 1_{A_1}(w_1)1_{A_2}(w_2)$. This is a simple consequence of measurability of $\pi$ in the $x$ argument, which is a hypothesis of a Markov kernel.

Comment: Coud you please take a look at [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4474833/47771). I*ve asked this one in order to solve that. Maybe the desired claimed must be reformulated though ...